# Parameters.AddWithValue not substituting placeholder text with actual values

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, parameter-passing

I am tryng to use Parameterised queries with MySQL. The theory seems pretty straight forward, you create a new instance of the **MySqlCommand** class like so:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
```

Set the **CommandText** property of this object to a MySQL query with placeholders like so:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `myTable` (`myField`) VALUES('@bar');
```

Use the **AddWithValue** method to replace my placeholder text with an actual value:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bar", "HelloWorld");
```

This is how I thought it worked, but in reality the word "@bar" ends up being appended, as opposed to "HelloWorld".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Parameters **never** substitute placeholder text. Parameters **are not placeholder text** - they are: *parameters*. That is *why and how* parameters solve things like SQL injection and query plan re-use.

Comment: @MarcGravell Apologies, I didn't know that there was a difference! Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try without wrapping in single quote

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `myTable` (`myField`) VALUES(@bar);
```